# Creating actor per domain object

Tags: routes, akka.net

I have been trying to use a router with a `ConsistentHashingPool` to create actors on the fly to consume messages on the basis of an object id, which in this simple case is a unique string.

I want an actor per domain aggregate and this seemed like a really simple way of doing it.

But the hashing seems to be doing odd things and sending messages to actors that have already been spawned from a different hash mapping value.

```
ActorSystem.ActorOf(
    Props.Create(() => new MyAggergateActor()).WithRouter(
        new ConsistentHashingPool(10)
        .WithHashMapping(o => (o as MyEvent)?.MyAggregateUniqueId ?? string.Empty)
        .WithResizer(new DefaultResizer(1, int.MaxValue))), 
    "myAggregateRouter");
```

Also tweaking values from the `nrOfInstances` seems to break things as well, meaning the hash maybe only works across the set of initial instances and no new actors are being spawned? I thought the resizer was supposed to help me here?

Please forgive any naivety, I have only just started using Akka.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key here is to understand what routers really do. Consistent hashing means, that given range of all possible consistent hash values, each of actors in router's pool is responsible for handling **range of hashes** from total range of possibilities.

For example: if your consistent hash can be one of the values from the possible range of 1-100, consistent hashing router with pool of 10 actors, will delegate messages with hashes from 1-10 to first actor, 11-20 to the second one, and so on... Once you'll resize the pool, those hash ranges will be re-adjusted to each actor in the pool - so in this case after resizing pool to 20 actors, first one will now serve ranges from 1-5, second 6-10 etc.

If you want to create actors on the fly and route messages to them based on some entity ID, I believe that the thing, you're looking for is [Akka.Cluster.Sharding](http://getakka.net/docs/clustering/cluster-sharding).

Comment: I think akka.cluster and sharding is totally overkill for my application. Also. However I think I was trying to be clever by using a round peg for a square hole. Now I understand the routers a bit better (thanks for your reply) I realise the error of my ways. Am now just using an actor to manage the instances and forward messages to the right instance.